# Outlook 2013 - reorder folder not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I did a search but I don't see my specific issue.

Just upgraded to Outlook 2013. I use the "Unread or For Follow Up" (UOFFU) folder as my home folder and would like it at the top of the list.

I had this setup in Outlook 2010, but in Outlook 2013 the UOFFU folder is under the search folder hierarchy, and no matter what I do I can't drag it out of there to reorder it.

I have searched and articles keep telling me it's possible, but my mileage is varying. Is there anyone who can do this and would you tell me how you did it?

[image: outlook 2013 - I want the unread or for followup folder to be at or above the Inbox.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to right click the search folder and show it in your Favorites list.  Once it's in the Favorites list, you can drag and reorder that list.

Another option is to ditch the search folder, make it a normal folder in your mailbox (either at a top level, or a subfolder of your Inbox), but I'm not sure what all goes into creating that search folder, so this option may not be feasible.

For illustration, here's a similar search folder I made; then after I have right clicked it and added it to my favorites; and finally while I was reordering the list.

[image]

Comment: I happen to think that tagging the search folder as Favorite is the most elegant solution.

Comment: This worked for me. My favorites view was turned off in the folder pane but once I went under View/Folder Pane/Show Favorites, it turned on and I was able to get set up with UOFFU. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't reorder search folders in Outlook 2013/2016. Outlook just applies alphabetical sorting to the list of search folders. You can benefit from it by renaming your search folders prefixing them with numbers.

Say,

```
1. Unread or For Follow Up
2. Missed Conversations
```

etc...